# Group an elasticsearch query with similar field and fetch both documents but together

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and trying to make queries.

I have an index where among other fields two fields are Sno and request_sno.

I want to make query where document/row with certain Sno should be followed by doc/row which has request_sno exactly same for previous Sno.

example,

1. Sno:1, name:'a', address:'b',..., request_sno:''
2. Sno:2, name:'', address:'',...., request_sno:1

These two should come together one row filled by other.

At first I thought of group by but I don't want aggregation.

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this usecase with [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) functionality of Elasticsearch.

For implement Collapse, your document should have one unique field. So lets create field call `collpase_id` which have value of `request_sno` and if `request_sno` is empty or null then copy value of `sno` field.

So your final document will be look like this:

```
     {
        "_index" : "collapse",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "kNNEbH4Bb7CAaZKC_vAY",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "sno" : 1,
          "name" : "a",
          "address" : "b",
          "collapse_id" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "collapse",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "kdNFbH4Bb7CAaZKC-PBM",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "sno" : 2,
          "name" : "a",
          "address" : "b",
          "request_sno" : 1,
          "collapse_id" : 1
        }
```

You can use below query to get collpase result

```
POST collapse/_search
{
  "_source": false,  
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "collapse_id",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "sno_reqsno_match",                  
      "size": 10
    }
  }
}
```

your result will look like below:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "collapse",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "kNNEbH4Bb7CAaZKC_vAY",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "collapse_id" : [
            1
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "sno_reqsno_match" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "collapse",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "kNNEbH4Bb7CAaZKC_vAY",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "sno" : 1,
                    "name" : "a",
                    "address" : "b",
                    "collapse_id" : 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "collapse",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "kdNFbH4Bb7CAaZKC-PBM",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "sno" : 2,
                    "name" : "a",
                    "address" : "b",
                    "request_sno" : 1,
                    "collapse_id" : 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "collapse",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ktNNbH4Bb7CAaZKC5PC8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "collapse_id" : [
            3
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "sno_reqsno_match" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "collapse",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "ktNNbH4Bb7CAaZKC5PC8",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "sno" : 3,
                    "name" : "a",
                    "address" : "b",
                    "collapse_id" : 3
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "collapse",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "k9NObH4Bb7CAaZKCGfAc",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "sno" : 4,
                    "name" : "a",
                    "address" : "b",
                    "request_sno" : 3,
                    "collapse_id" : 3
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```